# Remove end of URL with variable PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

I suuuuuck at regex and can't even begin to figure out how to remove everything from #edit to the end which contains a veriable of the url from this kind of URL:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_xpsyJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`edit.+$`](https://regex101.com/r/9umEXK/1)

Comment: @S.Jovan What would happen if `edit` was in the presentation id? : `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_editJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4/edit?usp=sharing`? 

Your solution would be to get rid of it. Use `edit\?.*` instead. That question mark will save your skin

Comment: Use `parse_url()` instead. If necessary, parse the path after that.

Comment: @S.Jovan Cheers, that worked!

Comment: For better accuracy use `\/edit\?.+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strstr()` with the third parameter set to `true` will be the cleanest, most direct non-regex approach. ...and you won't have to sweat your "suuuuucky" regex skills ;) This will isolate the substring from start of the string to the character before your search substring.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AECZg))

```
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_xpsyJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4/edit?usp=sharing';

echo strstr($url, '/edit', true);  // https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_xpsyJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4
echo "\n";
echo strstr($url, '/edit?', true);  // https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_xpsyJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4
```

*note: If the querystring (beginning witih `?`) will always exist after `/edit`, adding the `?` to the search substring can only improve accuracy.

Why is this the best function to call?  It doesn't leverage the overhead of calling the regex engine, it doesn't generate any temporary arrays, and it is a single function call as opposed to `substr()`-`strrpos()`.

If your use cases are a bit more complex and this approach is letting you down,  calling `parse_url()` should stabilize things sufficiently to allow you extract the appropriate url components.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gPUvg))

```
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_xpsyJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4/edit?usp=sharing';
$components = parse_url($url);
echo $components['scheme'], '://', $components['host'], strstr($components['path'],'/edit',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to parse the [query parameters](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url) at the end of the url. You can do so by using the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$url = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aa_xpsyJtslFJsg4UndsjDvlCe7Vu97_i6Q8zSKofy4/edit?usp=sharing";
print(explode('/edit', $url)[1]);
```

which will print

```
?usp=sharing
```